# Why not static class for the ListIterator defined in LinkedList?

Tags: java, static-members, listiterator

I am reading the Java Doc for LinkedList's ListIterator, which is defined as a non-static inner class. Why isn't it a static class? Shouldn't this data structure be shared among all instances of LinkedList? I am confused. Thanks.

```
private class ListItr implements ListIterator<E>{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a slight misunderstanding of the difference between static and non-static classes vs. static and non-static members in Java: the difference between a static and non-static classes is that non-static classes have an implicit member holding a reference to the outer class, while a static class has no such implicit reference. Both kinds of inner classes are shared among all instances; it's *instances* of inner classes that are tied to instances of their outer classes.

This is precisely what you want for iterators: each iterator is connected to the instance of the collection that it iterates, so it makes perfect sense to hold this reference implicitly by making the inner class non-static.

Comment: I tried adding "static" to the definition, and it didn't report any syntax error. In this case, both would have the same effect?

Comment: @user697911 Did you try it on the full source of the `ListItr` class, or simply on a stub? I would be rather surprised if the full source has compiled.

Comment: The full source LinkedList.java in Eclipse. You can try too.

Comment: @user697911 I am looking at the source [here (link)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.ListItr). If you switch the `ListIter` to `static`, lines 688, 698, 702 etc. and all other lines containing implicit references to `header` or `size` of the outer class would not compile.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't import the src into a Java project, so Eclipse doesn't report the syntax error.

Comment: @user697911 Does it report it now?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `ListItr` is ***not*** a data structure, its an inner class. `ListIterator` instances do not automatically share an instance of this class, and they should not! As an inner class `ListItr` has access to its enclosing classes data, which is great for implementing an iterator over a collection of data. A static class would ***not*** have this level of access and as such would make a much poorer choice as the implementation of an iterator.